# Default Category deleted by Mistake

Tags: category

I deleted default category by mistake. How can I get again. Have to create new root category name default category ? Then what is the configuration.

Comment: magento1 or magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Not so terrible if you delete the Root category like that. 
Now, just do those things:

- go to **Manage Categories**, add new **Root category**, name it whatever you want, not important.
- be sure that the **Root Category** you’ve created is **Enable**
- Drag all other categories into that Root Category.
- Then, this is **IMPORTANT : go to System -> Manage Stores, then click on your Store name**. **Set “Root category” field to the Category you’ve created ->done**

Gud luck.